# Touchesbegan method inactive from viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, touchesbegan

When I am adding a UIImageview from the viewcontroller, I want to make the touchesbeganmethod inactive till the uiimage is pressed.

Now I already have everything set up, I just need to know how I can prevent the gamescene from noticing touches by setting up code (only) in the viewcontroller.

Anyone knows how?

```
GameScene.paused = true // this pauses the game, but the touchesbegan method is still active!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `userInteractionEnabled` to false on the view you want to disable the touches or you could do the check on the begining in touches began like this:

```
if GameScene.paused == true {
    return
}
```